# AdColony Video Ad crashes when passing AdColonyAdDelegate as parameter in Robovm Binding

Tags: ios, libgdx, robovm, adcolony

I am using roboVM bindings for showing Adcolony video ads. When I use following code, it works perfectly:

```
AdColony.playVideoAd("ZONE_ID",null);
```

But if i want to use an AdDelegate, it crashes for the following code:

```
AdColony.playVideoAd("ZONE_ID", new AdColonyAdDelegate() {

        @Override
        public void onAdStartedInZone(String zoneID) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdAttemptFinished(boolean shown, String zoneID) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Can anybody help me resolve this issue?

Comment: When somebody asks to help with the crash, the question should show some crash logs, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use AdColonyAdDelegateAdapter in stead of AdColonyAdDelegate:

```
AdColony.playVideoAd("ZONE_ID", new AdColonyAdDelegateAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void onAdStartedInZone(String zoneID) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdAttemptFinished(boolean shown, String zoneID) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
})
```